# "The associated constraints are not satisfied" with custom requires clause

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

In one of my projects, I'm getting the error "the associated constraints are not satisfied" for one of my C++20 concepts. It appears to me that my code is correct, so I must misunderstand something about the language.

I have rewritten the code to remove all of the obviously extraneous details.

Here are the include statements:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
```

The constraint I'm defining is on the member function `Afunc` below:

```
template<typename BLikeType>
class A {
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<C> c_) : c_(std::move(c_)) {}

    template<typename... Args>
    requires requires (BLikeType t, Args... args) {
        {t.Bfunc(c_->Cfunc(args...))};
    }
    std::array<double, sizeof...(Args)> Afunc(Args... args) {
        return c_->Cfunc(args...);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_;
};
```

The classes `B` and `C` were written in a way to try to satisfy the constraint above. I use an `std::array<double, 2>` only so that readers understand that the variadic template in `A` is necessary.

```
class C {
public:
    C() {}

    std::array<double, 2> Cfunc(double a, double b) {
        return { a, b };
    }
};
```

I have also written a class `B` for the template parameter `BLikeType` in `A`. It is given below:

```
class B {
public:
    B(){}

    double Bfunc(std::array<double, 2> my_array) {
        return my_array[0] + my_array[1];
    }
};
```

I then try to test this constraint in my main function:

```
int main() {
    C c{};
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_ptr = std::make_shared<C>(c);

    A<B> a(c_ptr);
    std::array<double, 2> answer = a.Afunc<double, double>(.1, .2); // Error: the associated constraints are not satisfied

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this give the error that my constraint is not satisfied?

Comment: And I take that `answer` being `double` while `Afunc` returns an array is similarly a problem with the rewrite? This sort of thing is why we ask for a [mcve].

Comment: Also, especially after you've reduced the example, try a few different compilers with it - sites like https://godbolt.org/ makes it easy. Often the error messages from other compilers can be enlightening.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, I fixed it so that Bfunc now returns an ```std::array<int, 2>```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename... Args>
requires requires (BLikeType t, Args... args) {
    {t.Bfunc(c_->Cfunc(args...))};
}
std::array<double, sizeof...(Args)> Afunc(Args... args) {
    return c_->Cfunc(args...);
}
```

The *requires-clause* is not a complete-class context, so it can't see later-declared class members like `c_`. You can move the declaration of `c_` earlier in the class, but even then it won't see it with any necessary cv-qualification if the function is `const` (since the function declarator isn't seen at that point). Using a trailing requires-clause can solve that issue. In this case there's no extra cv-qualification to add, though, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: "The requires-clause is not a complete-class context, so it can't see later-declared class members like ```c_```." This part resolved my issue. The details about cv-qualification weren't clear, but I don't know much about those issues anyway, and they didn't stand in the way of my code compiling.